# Migration from Axis1.0 version to Axis2.0 version

Tags: java, apache-axis, upgrade, axis

Currently I am using Axis1 and axis2 both for JAVA now i want to migrate totally on axis 2.0 version, i have changed all axis 1.0 version jars into axis2.0 version jars except two jars...because i am not able to get the substitute or latest versions of that jars they are: **AXIS1.4_JARS/axis.jar and 
AXIS1.4_JARS/jaxrpc.jar** can anybody help me which jars can replace these jars or provide me the latest version of these jars for Axis2.0 version.

Comment: Moving from Axis 1 to Axis 2 is going to be no easier than moving to any other modern webservice stack - it will inevitably involve a complete rewrite.

Comment: Major version changes, in general, involve rewriting (at least part of) your code. If you could just replace JARs, it would be a minor version change.

Answer (score 2):

Axis2 is not compatible with Axis1.  It is a complete rewrite (and is, in my opinion, so over-engineered, that I decided to stick with Axis1).
So, migrating from Axis1 to Axis2 is definitely more involved than just replacing a couple of jar files.

Answer (score 1):

Read ["Migrating from Apache Axis 1.x to Axis2"](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/migration.html) article first. You should entirely remove old jars, add all the new jars from Axis2 and completely rewrite/recompile your applications.